# Get Date of phone activation

Tags: android, time, android-calendar

I'm trying to get the date (in `millis` or `Date` or `Calendar`) of when the phone was **activated**.
By activated I mean the first time it was turned on or the first turn on after it was formatted.

Is there any API to do that? Even an approximation would be sufficient.

Comment: I do not believe there is any trace available for this.

Answer (score 0):

For what I've seen that is not possible to accomplish, although there is some tricks to help you achieve that, check this link 
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59252 or this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51154

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was searching for an API.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is an api for this. :(
Although you can try and check the date of some files that the user or system did not change (if the device was not factory reseted). Or you can try a carrier approach (although this only applies if the carrier was always the same).